# ¿Por qué cuando quiero transformar varias variables me aparece el error SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python

Por ejemplo intento modificar a Datetime varias variables con el siguiente código:

```
for item in df_compas.iloc[:,[1,7,10]]:
    df_compas[item]=pd.to_datetime(df_compas[item])
```

y cuando ejecuto me aparece el error siguiente:

> *SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*

Lo he intentado con otras variables para cambiarlas a `category` y me sale el mismo error, he intentado hacerlo con `.iloc` y poniendo el nombre de las variables y me sale el mismo error también.

Comment: Aparentemente, lo que estás intentando modificar es una copia de un DataFrame (por ejemplo, df[a == "b"], te devuelve una copia) y Pandas, inteligentemente, detecta esto y te lo avisa. Si provees un dataframe de muestra y un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) podré darte una respuesta más elaborada.

Comment: Revisa de donde viene el DataFrame df_compas y mirá si haces algún proceso que copia el DataFrame, como df_compas = df[a == "b"] o df_compas = df.iloc[...].